# How does the oracle's Temporal Celerity revelation work when there otherwise wouldn't be a surprise round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, surprise, oracle

An [oracle with the time mystery](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo-oracle-mysteries/time/) can choose the Temporal Celerity revelation:

> *Temporal Celerity (Su)*: Whenever you roll for initiative, you can roll twice and take either result. **At 7th level, you can always act in the surprise round, but if you fail to notice the ambush, you act last, regardless of your initiative result (you act in the normal order in following rounds).** At 11th level, you can roll for initiative three times and take any one of the results.

What happens if the party enters a combat when there otherwise wouldn't be a surprise round? Does this effect trigger or no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If there is no surprise, the ability does nothing

You simply roll initiative twice and take the best result.

The surprise round only exists if at least one creature is unaware of their enemies. If both sides are expecting a fight and nobody on either side is surprised, there is simply no [surprise round](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#The_Surprise_Round).

> If some but not all of the combatants are aware of their opponents, a surprise round happens before regular rounds begin. (...) **If no one or everyone is surprised, no surprise round occurs**.